# Changes in Python text encoding / automativ newline conversion between 3.2 and 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, subprocess, pipe

I have a number of Python (3.2.3 32 bit) scripts handling mostly text files, partially executed via subprocess on Windows 7 64 bit, and sometimes using piping to create files.

Another system is setup with a newer ActiveState Python 3.3.4.1 because of the simplified installation process for some packages. On this system, the scripts have a different newline (win/mac/unix) behaviour and I would like to know what might be causing this.

According to https://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html the string representation has changed, but also IO modules and subprocess (https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) and even the system itself may be causing this.

I am not familiar enough with the python internals/development to quickly find out whether this is a deliberate change in behaviour or a bug:

http://bugs.python.org/issue?%40columns=id%2Cactivity%2Ctitle%2Ccreator%2Cassignee%2Cstatus%2Ctype&%40sort=-activity&%40filter=status&%40action=searchid&ignore=file%3Acontent&%40search_text=newline&submit=search&status=-1%2C1%2C2%2C3

Comment: There is no change in behaviour and it is not a bug. Look at `os.linesep` and `universal_newlines` parameter

Comment: OK, will look into it. For future reference, here are further links:
https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.linesep
https://docs.python.org/3.3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines

Comment: I've meant that `subprocess.Popen` has `universal_newlines` parameter: it makes the subprocess' output a text stream with the universal newlines support.